# "Default" iPhone SDK Version in MonoDevelop

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Under the "SDK Version" area of a MonoTouch project in MonoDevelop (Project Options -> Build -> iPhone Build -> General Tab) I currently have 3 options: "4.3", "5.0" and "Default".  Is it true that "Default" will automatically use the SDK that has the highest version number?  If not, what does it do?

For reference I'm using MonoTouch 5.0 and MonoDevelop 2.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is based on what's being returned from a native function call (it's not related to MonoTouch or MonoDevelop). That's likely not very helpful (and could even change, however unlikely).

If you want to know, specifically for your project, you add `-v -v -v` to your **additional touch arguments** (in your Project's Options, iPhone Build) then you should see the command-line options that MonoDevelop gives to `mtouch`. That will give your the *resolved* default into a (definitive) version number.

Comment: That did it, thanks.  My build output window now includes the following info: `Framework is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk`

Comment: Internally, MonoDevelop treats "Default" as if it were the highest version available.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will use the same version your xcode uses by default.